# How timer is getting set for Thread

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads

In my project i am seeeing creation one thread under another thread and inside a function of lowest child thread we are calling start timer

```
its.it_value.tv_sec = timeout / 1000;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = freq_nanosecs % 1000000000;
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

        (void)(timerfd_settime(m_timerHandleThread->m_fd, 0, &its, NULL));
```

My doubt is `timerfd_settime` this function will set timer of the current thread ? if yes please clarify what is meaning of seting the timer? Is it like this thread will automatically stop after some time or will it stop and again start ? If yes who will kill and who will start the thread

Comment: Did you read the [timerfd_settime man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timerfd_settime)? Or do any research on what that function does or search for some examples of how it is used?

Comment: timerfds have nothing to do with threads.

Answer (score 1):

[`timerfd_settime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) sets a kernel timer object which is associated with a file descriptor `m_timerHandleThread->m_fd`. On timer expiry `m_timerHandleThread->m_fd` becomes ready for read.

If you don't `read` or `poll`/`epoll` on the timer file descriptor nothing happens.

You should read [`timerfd_settime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) documentation.

Comment: As you stated "On timer expiry m_timerHandleThread->m_fd becomes ready for read " . That means "m_timerHandleThread->m_fd" is not readable untill the timer expires Am i correct ? Its means we cant access it in other function inside the thread

Comment: @TuhinPanda Read what _ready for read_ means in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html